# How to install openfire xmpp server in c-panel that has no SSH access?

Tags: xmpp, openfire

Is there any xmpp server that can be installed in my domain server that has no SSH access? Most of them uses ssh to install. I called customer service and said they don't allow ssh in my cpanel.